# Is there any way to create Hyperlinks inside TextArea? JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I would like to let the user create HyperLinks as they write inside a TextArea in the same way Microsoft Word lets you add Hyperlinks by highlighting and right-clicking while you write documents.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't put a [`Hyperlink`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Hyperlink.html) in a JavaFX [`TextArea`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html).

You can only edit plain text in a `TextArea`.

As an alternative consider using either:

1. A JavaFX Markdown editor based on TextArea, (a google search should reveal some examples) OR
2. The JavaFX [HTMLEditor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) (it doesn't have direct support for link editing, but maybe you could modify it to make it work) OR
3. The JavaFX [WebView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) with an embedded JavaScript editor which supports the editing you want (again, a web search might discover some editors which will work for you) OR
4. A JavaFX rich text editor such [`RichTextFX`](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX) if that has the editing capability you require.

Of the alternatives, a Markdown editor would be my favorite for most of these kinds of tasks.